# DateTime parse with CultureInfo on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I'm trying to parse a string into a DateTime object with a specific culture. This works great on my dev machine, unit tests and CI server, but for some reason it doesn't work on the production server. Instead I get System.FormatException:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown
>   word starting at index 0.

I have the following string as an example: `string dateString = "fr, 31 okt 2014 10:15:23";`

I can parse this in two ways:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
or
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
```

To me, this sounds like the production server, a Windows Server 2012 R2, don't understand the "fr" (Swedish abbreviation for Friday) and "okt" (Swedish abbreviation for October), despite having the "sv-SE" culture specified.

What have I missed?

Comment: That seems weird. I cannot reproduce and the CultureInfo is correctly set with 'fr' and 'okt'. Are you sure about the string passed? Did you have some kind of debugging tool to output that value before trying the conversion?

Comment: Your code works in my machine (.NET 4.5) and works on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/C1r170) as well. Are you sure your string doesn't have some secret character or something? What is your .NET Framework version by the way?

Comment: Thank's for the suggestions, but it is the same string. I've tested it with a constant and the behavior is still incorrect on the server. .Net framework is 4.5 and it works great on Win7 (eng), Win Srv 2k8r2 (eng), but not on Win 2012R2 (eng).

Comment: @mikaelnet I don't doubt you're right, but can you open the file using TextPad in Hex mode and give us the actual hexidecimal codes for that string? I wouldn't be surprised if a character *looks* like a normal ascii character but isn't.

Comment: I've checked the hex codes and they are ok. I've also tested a bunch of other dates with the same result. The strange thing is that the very same code works just fine on Win7/2k8 but not on 2k12. Is there any language pack that needs to be installed? (Never heard of such - .Net do find the sv-SE cultureInfo)